# Is there a way to give local "Everyone" user on web server "Full Control" to a folder in a website via web.config?

Tags: asp.net, security, iis

There is one sub-folder in my ASP.NET (web forms) website which needs the local "Everyone" user to have "Full Control" (I know, don't ask).

Every time I deploy a new version of my website I have to go through the pain of logging onto my web server, right-clicking the folder in question, choosing "Security" and adding the local "Everyone" account and specifying "Full Control".

Is there a way to do this in the site's web.config file so I can skip this step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, web.config file cannot specify file system ACL.

What you need is to modify your deploy routine so that it does not delete the existing folder but instead delete (if needed) just the contents.